# Do we need Validators if we are just writing a GET service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If I am writing the model, I can you know add validator for presence to be true,...etc but I was wondering if this model is meant to be used for a GET RESTful service then do I still need to have such validators in my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to validate a GET of data, then again, how will you get the information in?

Validations are only run if you save data to your database as described in the [Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)